# Can't get Spring Boot devtools auto restart get to work with 1.3M5 with Eclipse

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I cant get SpringBoot autorestart get to work. I simply create http://start.spring.io/ Gradle project with DevTools selected and run 'gradle eclipse' to create eclipse project and 'gradle bootRun' and now I can do some change in project  in Eclipse and this doesnt trigger auto restart at all. There is no message in bootRun console, no change detection. Any idea whats wrong here? I tried several times making starter project with http://start.spring.io and no way with auto restart ...

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gradle in Eclipse and Gradle on the command line use different directories for their compiled classes. The dev tools (launched via bootRun) will be looking in `build/classes` whereas Eclipse will be compiling your changes into `bin/classes`. Rather than launching your app using `gradle bootRun`, try launching it in Eclipse instead using Run As -> Java application.

Comment: Thanks, I was running my application using mvn spring-boot:run, it didn't work. Now I am launching it in Eclipse with Run As -> Java application and it works

Comment: This also works for Maven -- run as Java Application instead of Maven Build.

Answer (score 3):

In one terminal:

```
gradle build --continuous
```

In second terminal:

```
gradle bootRun
```

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/continuous-auto-restart-with-spring-boot-devtools

BTW, I find it take longer time than the eclipse.

Comment: voted, But it needs 2 commands while `mvn` only need `mvn spring-boot:run`, pretty bad.